# UIView as maskView- origin shifted by constraint constants

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint, cgpoint

I am attempting to implement a user-used photo crop tool and am stuck. I have a `UIView` (`imageCropper`) that is on top (z-order-wise) of the `UIImageView` (`imageToBeEdited`) which contains the image that is being cropped. If I run the app at this point, with my other configurations and logic, `imageCropper` is right on top of the image. However, when I set the `maskView` of `imageToBeEdited` to `imageCropper`, the origin of `imageCropper` shifts. After messing with the constraint constants, I determined that it is shifting to a greater x by the exact value of the leading constraint and a greater y by the exact value of the top constraint.

Another piece of info that makes this even more confusing, is that I have another `UIView` (`imageCropperBorder`) on top (again z-order-wise) of `imageCropper` that acts simply as a visible border. I set it's frame to the exact same frame as `imageCropper` and yet it is where they are both supposed to be.

I have no constraints set on `imageCropper` or `imageCropperBorder`.

My questions are **why is `imageCropper` shifting and how do I resolve this issue?**

After trying several different methods to create a user-enabled, smoothly moving cropping tool I came back to this solution and simply created x and y offsets by programmatically grabbing the constraints' values in the `viewDidLoad` and then adjusting the origin of `imageCropper` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and that worked.

However, I have a `panGestureRecognizer` set up on the `ViewController`'s view. Once I start dragging the photo (`imageCropper`) to crop it, the `imageCropper` origin shifts down again. I tried adding the offset logic into the function that handles the recognizer, but it seems to be compounding the change and sending the frame off the screen. (I am resetting the translation with each receipt of a recognizer.)

**Code:**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    resizedImageFrame = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(imageToEdit.image!.size, imageToEdit.bounds)
    let resizedImageCenter = imageToEdit.center
    let resizedImageX = resizedImageCenter.x - (resizedImageFrame.width / 2)
    let resizedImageY = resizedImageCenter.y - (resizedImageFrame.height / 2)
    resizedImageFrame.origin = CGPoint(x: resizedImageX, y: resizedImageY)
    currentImageFrame = resizedImageFrame
    imageCropperBorder.frame = resizedImageFrame
    imageCropper.frame = CGRectOffset(resizedImageFrame, -cropperXOffset, -cropperYOffset)
    // imageCropper.frame above is set with the offset discussed. If I set it
    // to simply resizedImageFrame it does NOT appear where imageCropperBorder is
}
```

As always, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `imageCropper` as `imageView`'s maskView. It will use the `imageView`'s coordinate system to position the `imageCropper`, so for `imageCropper`, point (0,0) is not at the `ViewController`'s view's top-left corner but `imageView`'s top-left corner.

Comment: I would add that setting a view as a maskView makes it a subview of that view. (I finally checked this calling .superview.) Also, because I was dealing with a resized image I had to do some calculations and could not use the superview's bounds as is. Thanks for the help.